# Retry mechanism for Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, system-design, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

Here's a reformatted version of your Stack Overflow question:

I am already familiar with how the `@Retry` annotation from Resilience4j works for synchronous functions, but I'm unsure of how to design an Auto Retry mechanism for Kafka calls. Here's the scenario:

1. I need to publish a message to Kafka on `topic_1`.
2. The message is consumed by an external service.
3. The external service sends a callback on `topic_2`.
4. Based on the callback event received on `topic_2`, we decide whether to republish the message to `topic_1` or not.

I'm looking for guidance on how to implement Auto Retry for Kafka calls in this scenario. Is there a framework available that can help with this, or should I implement it myself? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
One more question, `@Retry` block the current thread for the time until all retry attempts are exhausted ? I couldn't find this anywhere in documentation.